# Moving directories

Tags: filesystem, directory

If I use the `cp` command to copy a directory A to the inside of directory B, will it double the amount of space that it takes up (directory A + copied version of directory A)? I can't imagine that would be the case, but would it disturb the look up time on disk for the files in that directory?

I am a beginner so I'm sorry if this question doesn't really make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`cp` copies files.  If you specify a directory (I've never tested this) it would probably copy the contents of this directory, and place them all (including the original folder) into the destination directory.  Yes, it will create two copies of the target file(s) and yes, it will probably disturb a number of things like that.

You can drag and drop files easily in Nautilus to move them naturally, without the negative effects on hard drive optimization.  The `mv` command in terminal will do the same thing.  It's similar in usability to the cp command:

```
mv </oldlocation/target> </newlocation/destination/>
```

Where the target is a file, or a directory, and the destination is a directory.

NOTE:  If you use `mv </location/filenameA> <location/filenameB>` it will rename the file.
For example,

```
mv /etc/x11/xorg.conf /etc/x11/xorg.conf.backup
```

will rename the `xorg.conf` text file to `xorg.conf.backup`.  Try doing a google search of useful linux command line tools.

Another neat trick in command line is using the 'man' option.  For example

```
mv man
```

or

```
sudo man
```

The 'man' stands for manual.  Every terminal application has a manual detailing the nature of the application, all of it's options, and definitions for everything.  You can run the man option with any terminal command you install.

Comment: Right, I understand that, I guess the way I should have framed the question is that if I copy a directory, is that just going to create another pointer to where those files are stored (I am assuming sequentially on disk) or will actually burn another directory A sized space on disk, or screw with the way it does the look up in a bad way. Like I said, I'm very noob, and maybe this is too complicated a question for me to understand the answer without doing alot more research.

Comment: Look up some videos or articles on google/youtube about how the linux filesystem works.  It's VERY different than in Windows, it's actually fascinating.  Linux writes files the HDD physically at the very beginning of every HDD stripe, and continues with the next encoding if there is any space left, and adds the remainder onto the next stripe, and so on. It's much faster at file access than Windows because of this.  It also maps files digitally rather than physically.  Files aren't moved stripes like in Windows.  You never have to defrag in Linux.

Comment: If you use `cp` to copy a directory, it will emit a notice telling you it is ignoring the directory, and do nothing.  You need to use `-r` (or better, `-a` to preserve some other attributes), to copy a directory, as it turns on recursion (entering a directory to copy its contents).

Answer (score 2):

The move command in linux is `mv`, see `mv --help` for more info

this moves the directory and all sub dirs

```
mv -f dir1 /destinationDir
```

This move files from dir1 to dir2

```
mv -f dir1/* dir2
```

Comment: Right, but I want to have the exact same directory in another directory.

Answer (score 0):

Adding an answer because this was my first search result in Google and there wasn't many thorough answers on the mv command, and what linking means at any level of detail.

**cp** - copies. It will make an identical copy by default, taking up identical space, although you can tell cp to make hard links (pointers to each file) using the -l option.

If you want to create a copy of a folder, do this:

```
cp -a source dest
```

Where -a means an "archive" or identical copy, including folders and links.  You could exchange it for -r if you want to copy folders but not links.

If you want to create a copy with links to the original files (changing the original changes the copy as well, and takes up much less space), do this:

```
cp -l source dest
```

**ln** - links. It will make only a link, you can have it point to your destination, and it will only take up the space it takes to point to it.

**If you want to create a single link to a folder, just do this:**

```
ln -s source dest
```

NOTE:  -s means "symbolic" link. Because ln can create hard or soft (most people call this "symbolic") links.  Hard links can only point to files and have other restrictions, while symbolic links can point to anything, including folders.  For a complete article on differences between hard and soft links see this great article [here](https://medium.com/@wendymayorgasegura/what-is-the-difference-between-a-hard-link-and-a-symbolic-link-8c0493041b62).

**mv** - moves files or folders.

To move folders (or files) just do this:

```
mv source dest
```

Comment: It may be worth mentioning that without `-r` or `-a`, `cp` will only copy files (that is, `source` must be a file), and will ignore directories.

Comment: `cp -a` also preserves owner and group ID's I think.